# custom class data not showing in to the tableview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

hi am fetching from data from firebase and stored into custom class and displaying into the tableview, when I displaying tableview its not showing empty but when I am calling with another array data its working fine

```
class datapass {

        var fullName : String?
        var status : String?
        var dateAndTimeofVisit :String?
        var profilephot :String?
        var uid :String?
        var inviterUID: String?
        init(fullname:String?,status:String?,dateAndTimeofVisit:String?,profilephot:String,uid:String?,inviterUID:String?) {
            self.fullName = fullname
            self.status = status
            self.dateAndTimeofVisit = dateAndTimeofVisit
            self.profilephot = profilephot
            self.uid = uid
            self.inviterUID = inviterUID

        }

    }
```

inside viewdidload

```
          var datapassval = [datapass]()

     HandedDataRef = Database.database().reference()
                .child(Constants.FIREBASE_CHILD_VISITORS)
                .child(Constants.FIREBASE_CHILD_PRE_APPROVED_VISITORS).child("-LHO1TuRZTKCZV5Mli13")
            HandedDataRef?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
                print("snapshot values",snapshot)
                if snapshot.exists() {

                    let visitorData = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]

                    print("visitordata",visitorData as Any)

                    let dateAndTimeOfVisit = visitorData?[VisitorListFBKeys.dateAndTimeOfVisit.key] as? String
                    let fullName = visitorData?[VisitorListFBKeys.fullName.key] as? String
                    let inviterUID = visitorData?[VisitorListFBKeys.inviterUID.key] as? String
                    let mobileNumber = visitorData?[VisitorListFBKeys.mobileNumber.key] as? String
                    let profilePhoto = visitorData?[VisitorListFBKeys.profilePhoto.key] as? String
                    let status = visitorData?[VisitorListFBKeys.status.key] as? String
                    let uid = visitorData?[VisitorListFBKeys.uid.key] as? String


                    self.datapassval.append(datapass.init(fullname: fullName, status: status , dateAndTimeofVisit: dateAndTimeOfVisit, profilephot: profilePhoto!, uid: uid, inviterUID: inviterUID))


                }
            })



     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return datapassval.count //count getting 0 

        }



        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! HandedThingsToGuestTableViewCell

     let datamy = datapassval[indexPath.row]
            print("datamy",datamy)
cell.lbl_VisiterName.text = datamy.fullName
}
```

its not showing any thing how to display custom class data where I did mistake

Comment: when calling this was getting empty values

Comment: Is your array full of data?

Comment: Btw you don't return cell in  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload the table

```
self.datapassval.append(datapass.init(fullname: fullName, status: status , dateAndTimeofVisit: dateAndTimeOfVisit, profilephot: profilePhoto!, uid: uid, inviterUID: inviterUID))
self.tableView.reloadData()
```